# Passing data to one of many components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to create a DownloadButton component in VueJS that animates when clicked, and stops animating upon completion of the download. The DownloadButton component will be used in a table where its repeated many times. I want the download method to be contained in the parent. The problem is that changing the loading variable causes all the components to be affected rather than just the one being clicked.

Parent:

```
<DownloadButton @click.native="download" :loading="loading"></DownloadButton>
<DownloadButton @click.native="download" :loading="loading"></DownloadButton>
<DownloadButton @click.native="download" :loading="loading"></DownloadButton>

methods: {
   download() {
       this.loading = true
       // wait for the download procedure to finish...
       this.loading = false
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm a little unfamiliar with the syntax you are using, but 2 ways I know of doing this is either to assign individual classes to your download buttons, or use "this" within your click event to target the parent element you clicked on and build your logic from there.

Comment: I don't know how to do that using VueJS

Comment: Okay now I understand why the syntax doesn't look familiar, I've never used vueJS. However if I gave you the code in raw javascript to target the specific element you clicked on, would you be able to connect that code to the "methods" that vueJS is using? If not the only other way I can help is if you tell me what exactly these methods are doing (as in hiding/showing a different version of the loader image) and I can convert it all into raw js.

Comment: I actually know how to do it using jQuery, but I want to use VueJS to make a reusable component. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should monitor loading state **of each button** not just global loading.

Here is quick and simple example of what you want I think:

```js
Vue.component("download-button", {
 template: "#dbTemplate",
  props: ['loading'],
  computed: {
   stateText() {
        return this.loading ? 'Loading...' : 'Load';
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    resources: [
     { date: new Date(), url: "some-url1" },
      { date: new Date(), url: "some-url2" },
      { date: new Date(), url: "some-url3" },
      { date: new Date(), url: "some-url4" }
    ],
    resourceStates: {}
  },
  methods: {
   downloadResource(resource) {
     this.$set(this.resourceStates, resource.url, true);
     new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          setTimeout(() => resolve(new Date()), 1000);
      }).then((date) => {
       resource.date = date;
       this.$set(this.resourceStates, resource.url, false);
      })
    },
    isLoading(resource) {
     return !!this.resourceStates[resource.url];
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="res in resources" :key="res.url" style="padding: 10px 0">
    {{ res.date.toLocaleString() }}&nbsp;
    <download-button  @click.native="downloadResource(res)" :loading="isLoading(res)">
    </download-button>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/template-x" id="dbTemplate">
 <button :disabled="loading">
   {{ stateText }}
 </button>
</script>
```

Comment: Very cool, I didn't know that we could use methods as props, thanks!